# how can I populate html file with results from json while using express.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, mean-stack

I have a webpage with a small `index.html` page:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="photos">
    </div>
</body>
...
```

It is placed in a `/public` folder of my app and thanks to the following `server.js` file - it works:

```
mongoose.connect(properties.get('db.path'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.set('trust proxy');

app.get('/:hashtag', function(req, res){
    var query = Photo.find({"hashtags":{$in: [req.params.hashtag]}});
        query.exec(function(err, photos) {
            if(err) {
                sendError(res, err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(photos);
    });
});

console.log('App listening on port ' + port);
server.listen(port);
```

When user goes to `mydomain.com`, he sees that empty html file. Now as you see in my `server.js` I have a possibility of including hashtags in my query, so user can type `mydomain.com/test`. Currently when he does it, all he sees is a json file, which is either empty:

```
[]
```

or has some content:

```
[{"_id":"some_id","photo_url":"some_url","hashtags":["photo","test"]},
{"_id":"some_id2","photo_url":"some_url2","hashtags":["photo2","test"]}]
```

how can I show my webpage with those images embedded, instead of showing plain json to the user?

Comment: You might want to look into [template engines](http://expressjs.com/de/guide/using-template-engines.html) such as [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equip your app with a template engine:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.set('trust proxy');
// config views =============================================
app.set('views', './views') // specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs') // register the template engine
=============================================================
```

Use `res.render()` instead of `res.json()` to render your templates with desired data:

```
app.get('/:hashtag', function(req, res){
    var query = Photo.find({"hashtags":{$in: [req.params.hashtag]}});
        query.exec(function(err, photos) {
            if(err) {
                sendError(res, err);
                return;
            }
            // res.json(photos);
            res.render('index', { title: 'my photos', photos: photos })
    });
});
```

in `index.html` loop over `photos` collection and print em out:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="photos">
       <% photos.forEach(function(photo) { %>
          <img src=<% photo.photo_url %> >
       <% }); %>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

Note that your `index.html` should reside in `./views/index.html` path; as we set this path for our views.

Comment: thank you man, it works of course :) one more question though - now it works when user provides any hashtag after the domain name. How can I make it work so that it runs query `var query = Photo.find();` when user does not provide any hashtag? For example when he goes to `mydomain.com/hashtag` it now looks for all photos with specific hashtag, but how should I modify server.js file to support entries on `mydomain.com`?

Comment: @user3766930 define a root route: `app.get('/', ...` just like `app.get('/:hashtag', ...` and run `var query = Photo.find();` query instead to get all photos and serve it just like what we did with **hashtag**ed version and have a look at [express's](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) documentation ;)